# stubbing templates in RSpec functional tests

Tags: templates, rspec, stub, stubbing

So I'm working on a gem that provides helpers for use with the [Jeditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) jQuery plugin, called [jeditable-rails](https://github.com/afeld/jeditable-rails).  These helpers are essentially writing javascript that create forms.

I am looking to stub templates within the request/controller specs, doing something like this:

```
gadget = Gadget.create!(:name => 'foo')
stub_template 'gadgets/edit.html.erb' => "<%= editable_field(@gadget, :name) %>"
# using Capybara
visit edit_gadget_path(gadget)
# fill out form, submit, etc.
```

When I run this in a request spec, I get the error `undefined method 'stub_template'`.  Is it possible to use `stub_template` in request specs, or is there a different way to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

This is Ruby, so it's probably possible, but it's not a given.

RSpec request specs delegate most of their work to Rails integration tests, which support multiple requests and, therefore, multiple controllers/views. `stub_template` requires access to a view instance, which we don't have access to in request specs.

Comment: Hmm, maybe controller specs?  Thanks for the reply!